# Call function in a html <td> tag with thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

How can I pass `${policies.getId()` correctly in  function, while looping through `${policies}`?

```
    <html>
        ... 
        <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr  th:each="policies : ${policies}" >
                  <td th:object="${policies.getId()}" onload="myFunction01(object)"></td>
                  <td th:object="${policies.getName()}" onload="myFunction02(object)"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

    <script th:inline="javascript">
    function myFunction01(object){...} 
    function myFunction02(object){...} 
     </script>  
</html>
```

Comment: can you bit clear what actually you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this and let me know if this worked for you

```
th:onload ="'myFunction01(\'' + ${policies.getId()} + '\');'"
```